# Adding a case statment to SQL join statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Im trying to format all my DATA in my sql before display information

Both my joins work fine, I have a piece of data (status) that has associated titles to go with the value but the `CASE` statment isn't working. I currently have a PHP swtich statement that does this data conversion but I'd like to do it in SQL if possible

```
SELECT
 l.leadid, l.companyname, l.status, l.dateadded, addedby.name AS addedby, assignedto.name AS assignedto, l.address, l.city, l.prov, l.country, l.postalcode,
 l.phone, l.fax, l.facebook, l.twitter, l.youtube, l.instagram, l.website, l.logo
FROM leads l
  INNER JOIN staff addedby ON l.addedby = addedby.staffid
  INNER JOIN staff assignedto ON l.assignedto = assignedto.staffid
    CASE l.status
     WHEN l.status = 7 THEN l.status = 'Converted'
     WHEN l.status = 6 THEN l.status = 'Hot'
     WHEN l.status = 5 THEN l.status = 'Warm'
     WHEN l.status = 4 THEN l.status = 'Open'
     WHEN l.status = 3 THEN l.status = 'NEW'
     WHEN l.status = 2 THEN l.status = 'Cold'
       ELSE l.status = 'Dead'
     END    
     WHERE l.leadid = $id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case should be in the `SELECT` list, not after the `INNER JOIN`.
Also second issue is the use of l.status = after each THEN statement. MySql syntax only requires the final value after the THEN statement, not a value assignment.

Also note that you don't need the `l.status =` part in your `when` statements, because the `case value` is listed next to the `CASE` statement. If you were building an ad hoc case statement, then it would be needed. So, you can just write it as follows:

I would just write it as follows:

```
SELECT
    l.leadid, 
    l.companyname, 
    CASE l.status
        WHEN 7 THEN 'Converted'
        WHEN 6 THEN 'Hot'
        WHEN 5 THEN 'Warm'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'Open'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'NEW'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'Cold'
        ELSE 'Dead'
    END As Status, 
    l.dateadded, 
    < rest of your fields >
FROM leads l
    INNER JOIN staff addedby ON l.addedby = addedby.staffid
    INNER JOIN staff assignedto ON l.assignedto = assignedto.staffid
WHERE l.leadid = $id
```

Comment: it returns a 0, if that because the column is classified as an INT and im changing it to chars?

Comment: @user934902 I think the issue might be the "l.status = " after each THEN statement; only the value is needed there, try my second way of writing  it and see if that works.

Answer (score 3):

1. You want your `CASE` in `SELECT` clause
2. Your `CASE` syntax is invalid
3. As an alternative you can use a MySQL (since your question tagged with `mysql`) specific less verbose function `ELT()`

That being said you can do either

```sql
SELECT
       l.leadid, l.companyname, 
       CASE l.status
         WHEN 7 THEN 'Converted'
         WHEN 6 THEN 'Hot'
         WHEN 5 THEN 'Warm'
         WHEN 4 THEN 'Open'
         WHEN 3 THEN 'NEW'
         WHEN 2 THEN 'Cold'
         ELSE 'Dead'
       END status, 
       l.dateadded, addedby.name AS addedby, 
       assignedto.name AS assignedto, l.address, 
       l.city, l.prov, l.country, l.postalcode,
       l.phone, l.fax, l.facebook, l.twitter, 
       l.youtube, l.instagram, l.website, l.logo
  FROM leads l JOIN staff addedby 
    ON l.addedby = addedby.staffid JOIN staff assignedto 
    ON l.assignedto = assignedto.staffid   
WHERE l.leadid = $id
```

or

```sql
SELECT
       l.leadid, l.companyname, 
       IFNULL(ELT(l.status - 1, 'Cold', 'New', 'Open', 'Warm', 'Hot', 'Converted'), 'Dead') status,
       l.dateadded, addedby.name AS addedby, 
       assignedto.name AS assignedto, l.address, 
       l.city, l.prov, l.country, l.postalcode,
       l.phone, l.fax, l.facebook, l.twitter, 
       l.youtube, l.instagram, l.website, l.logo
  FROM leads l JOIN staff addedby 
    ON l.addedby = addedby.staffid JOIN staff assignedto 
    ON l.assignedto = assignedto.staffid   
WHERE l.leadid = $id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/82d0f/3)** demo (for both cases)

Answer (score -2):

Try It

```
SELECT
 l.leadid, l.companyname, l.status, l.dateadded, addedby.name AS addedby, assignedto.name AS assignedto, l.address, l.city, l.prov, l.country, l.postalcode,
 l.phone, l.fax, l.facebook, l.twitter, l.youtube, l.instagram, l.website, l.logo, CASE l.status
     WHEN l.status = 7 THEN l.status = 'Converted'
     WHEN l.status = 6 THEN l.status = 'Hot'
     WHEN l.status = 5 THEN l.status = 'Warm'
     WHEN l.status = 4 THEN l.status = 'Open'
     WHEN l.status = 3 THEN l.status = 'NEW'
     WHEN l.status = 2 THEN l.status = 'Cold'
       ELSE l.status = 'Dead'
     END
FROM leads l
  INNER JOIN staff addedby ON l.addedby = addedby.staffid
  INNER JOIN staff assignedto ON l.assignedto = assignedto.staffid    
WHERE l.leadid = $id
```

Comment: Missing 'END AS status' otherwise the case returns as a column title

Comment: Did you test this?  If you post code that you haven't tested, you risk getting downvotes.